# jQuery plugin for textarea with options of inserting special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for jQuery plugin that has options of selecting different fonts, gives different options to user to insert special characters. Please let me know if it is possible through some other javascript or html code

Answer (score 1):

My favorite is still Markitup: [Link](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/) This will satisfy your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. TinyMCE is also an option that I found out.